# Correct type hinting for next() function and generators

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

Just playing around with understanding type hinting in python using PyCharm, and came across the following:

```py
def range_iter(self, val: int):
    yield from range(val)

range_itterable = range_iter(10)

# Type hinting reports that next() returns a 'range'
type(next(range_itterable)) # but actual returned type is 'int'
```

What's the way to make the type hinting system happy here?

Comment: Make it a habit to properly and _fully_ annotate your functions; then you will not run into these issues. (Unless there are bugs in the static type checkers involved of course.) Your IDE has to use all sorts of (frankly unnecessary) hacks to figure out what your function _might_ return, unless you state it explicitly. That will just lead to more confusion and ambiguity. [_Explicit is better than implicit._](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the type hint for `range_iter()` suggests it returns a range, but it actually returns integers from the range function. My bet is this is confusing Pycharm.

You can specify the actual return type, which is an iterable of integers. Use `from typing import Iterator` and specify `Iterator[int]` as the return type.

```
from typing import Iterator

def range_iter(val: int) -> Iterator[int]:
    yield from range(val)

range_iterable = range_iter(10)

# Type hinting reports that next() returns an 'int'
type(next(range_iterable))  # returns 'int'
```

Comment: PyCharm now reports: "Expected type 'SupportsNext' (matched generic type 'SupportsNext[_T]'), got 'Iterable[int]' instead"

Comment: I switched `Iterable` to `Iterator` -- I am not seeing your problem on VSCode.

Comment: Yeah, from reading a few other similar questions, seems like PyCharm uses it's own type-hinting system, where VSCode uses PyLance, so this might just be a PyCharm thing

Comment: @torrentails You are misusing the term "type hinting". Type hinting is the practice of adding type hints/annotations to your code. An IDE can provide auto-suggestions, warnings, insights etc. based on results it gets from its **static type checker**. PyCharm has its own static type checker. Pyright (used by Pylance) is another. The standard one is Mypy. To this answer: `Iterable` is not specific enough, its subtype `Iterator` is necessary. Not a "PyCharm thing", just a typing thing. For `next` requires the `__next__` method, which is part of the `Iterator` protocol.